# Continuous "Temporary failure resolving repositories"

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, dns

Since I moved country (i.e. to say different location, new network, etc. but same machine) I have problems updating the package list. It does not matter if I run `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt update` or I use synaptic. Some repositories will always fail (every time different ones, it is not always the same one).

So far I tried changing DNS (I have openDNS and GoogleDNS set for the general nework) and I forced, by manually editing, `/etc/resolv.conf` to use as well a GoogleDNS. Despite some improvement (not all fail, but less) it did not solve the problem.

Is it a configuration problem? Is it a problem of my provider/connection?
Do you know how it could be solved?

Comment: Look in the sources list are there any country designations in there?

Comment: Aside the official ubuntu repository (which I set to the best server with Synaptic, resulting in Estonian one despite I am in Spain), the other do not have a country (all .com or .net). Nevertheless, I don't think that's the problem. Ubuntu repos failed before that were still set in NL, as well as now that are in EE. And this behavior seems random to me.